# How to get Xpath with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of elements after using `find_elements` method. The list contains soemthing like this

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b816a8a89e827bd47f5d2c7e66169c67", element="ed2cb578-6222-41cc-ab44-d3e183f48935")>
```

Is there a way to get the Xpath of each one from something like session or element which I think is unique, because I need to access each one's child and parent?

```
alist = list
sleep(5)
for session in alist:
    self.Name = session.find_element('xpath', '//a[contains(@href, "student")]').text
    print(self.Name)
```

Example of element containing child in a table:

```
<tr style="border-bottom:2px solid black !important;">
    <td>
      <div>
        <a href="http://bequran.uk/student/profile/2032">Name</a>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: also if there is a way to access them without the xpath, it will be great

Comment: So your actual goal is XPath or accessing child/parent of current WebElement?

Comment: yes Curious Koala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you found WebElement with `find_elements`/`find_element` you can select its child/parent with XPath or other locator types e.g.

```
element = driver.find_element(...)
parent = element.find_element('xpath', './parent::*')
child = element.find_element('class name', 'some_class_name')
```

**Update**

If you want to select child of element you need to specify **context node** (note the leading `.`):

```
session.find_element('xpath', './/a[contains(@href, "student")]').text
```

Comment: it still doesn't get the element's child, however it searches the whole page and there are other elements with same xpath

Comment: @OmarYacop Can you share some HTML and your current code?

Comment: just added the code and an example of the HTML

Comment: so there is a table of <tr>, I want to access each one's <a> and get their names